# How Can I Load Ads Particular Level?

Tags: unity, mathematics, scene, advertisements, admob

How Can I Apply Ads Different Level??
I Create A 40 Level,

Ex:

- Level1 complete then load ads Interstitial
- Level2 complete then load ads Interstitial
- Level3 complete then load ads Rewarded
- Level4 complete then load ads Rewarded
- Level5 complete then load ads Interstitial
- Level6 complete then load ads Interstital

follow this same pattern in further levels(40)

Code:

```
 public string currentscenename;

 public string nextscenename;

 public void Next()        //code for next level                                
  {
        int num = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level", 0);            
        Debug.Log("Num1:" + num);            
        num++;                                                                                                             

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", num);   

        if (currentscenename == nextscenename)                                  
        {
            Next();
            Debug.Log("loadlevel");
        }
        else
        { 
             if (num % 4 == 3 || num % 4 == 0)         // it is working absolutely fine                                                                                           
            {
                //DebugPanel.Log("num1", "num2" + num % 4);

                if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())                                                                                
                {
                     rewardBasedVideo.Show();   //this line generate reward ads
                    //DebugPanel.Log("rewarded", "rewardedads");
                    //DebugPanel.Log("inside ads" , "inside ads function");
                    Debug.Log("rewarded 1");
                }
            }
            if(num % 4 == 2 || num % 4 == 1)                                                                                               //1 and 2 
            {
                myclass.CallAds.Instance.AdsRequest();    //this line generate interstitial ads
                DebugPanel.Log("num" , "num" + num % 4);
                Debug.Log("interstitial 2");
            }
            SceneManager.LoadScene(nextscenename);
        }
  }





**Maths:**     problem is here my condition will not be run when coming Level5 and Level10,Level15,Level20,Level25,Level30,Level35,Level40
5 mod 4 =  1
10 mod 4 = 2     


Problem is when coming Level5 and Level10 then not showning ads????plz help
```

I m Using Google AdmobAds: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start

Referance:

[image]

Comment: Other users might be able to help you better if you mention which Ad network you are using

Comment: @Shraa1 i m using google admob ads

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)` but will be depreciated sometime so the docs say to subscribe to the SceneManagers sceneLoaded

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class YourAdScript: MonoBehaviour
{
   void Start
   {
     SceneManager.sceneLoaded+= this.OnLevelLoaded;   
   }

   void OnLevelLoaded(Scene scene,LoadSceneMode mode)
   {
     //play ad
     if(rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())                                                                                
       {
          rewardBasedVideo.Show();//this line generate rewarded ads
       }
   }
   void OnDisable
   {
      SceneManager.sceneLoaded-= this.OnLevelLoaded;   
   }
}
```

note : be sure to unsubscribe in OnDisable().